# JS/jQuery - Transform phone number and email to show only first and last characters

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string-matching

How do I dynamically transform phone numbers and email from an API response to hide the non extreme character?

For Ex:

1. The Invoice will be sent to you email: n*****1@gmail.com
2. OTP will be sent to your phone number: 7******213

The API contains key:values so I will get phone# and email isolated, so no need to sieve them from a larger string.Also phone numbers are always 10 digits and I need to show the 1st and last three digits.

PS: I suck at regex :(

Comment: Use `substr()` to get the parts of the string you want. Or use a regular expression.

Comment: You can hide part of phone or email in browser but API response contains full info. (And interested user can find it). Do it on server side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following extended solution using `String.split`, `String.replace`, `String.slice` and ES6 `String.repeat` functions:

```
var email = "nick_tomson1@gmail.com", phone = "7112459213";

function transformEntry(item, type) {
    switch (type) {
        case 'email':
            var parts = item.split("@"), len = parts[0].length;
            return email.replace(parts[0].slice(1,-1), "*".repeat(len - 2));
        case 'phone':
            return item[0] + "*".repeat(item.length - 4) + item.slice(-3);
       default: 
            throw new Error("Undefined type: " + type);
    }        
}

console.log(transformEntry(email, 'email'));  // n**********1@gmail.com
console.log(transformEntry(phone, 'phone'));  // 7******213
```

Comment: This works for me. There was a mistake in showing last 3 digits of phone number. Fixed it.

Comment: @eNeMetcH, I apologize, I've missed that moment unintentionally. Thanks for pointing out

Answer (score 5):

To convert the phone numbers use this:

```
'740-344-4484'.replace(/(\d{1})(.*)(\d{3})/, '$1******$3')
```

And finally, to convert the emails:

```
'ScarlettAppleton@dayrep.com'.replace(/(\w{1})(.*)(\w{1})@(.*)/, '$1******$3@$4')
```

The outputs are, respectively:

```
"7******484" 
"S******n@dayrep.com"
```

Comment: I was hoping to maintain the email character length to original.